# How to find the relative xpath notation from a node to its child node in xslt ?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I am relatively new to xslt, but I have had some luck styling a huge xml file. Now i am stuck in a place and not able to proceed. Lets say the structure of the xml file is somewhat like

```
<xxx>
.......
.......
.......
 <Field id="123" type="fld" elem="3">
   <td:value passed="true"> 25 </td:value>
 </Field>
.......
.......
.......

</xxx>
```

I am currently in the Field node. If i do a `<xsl:value of select="name()" />` it gives out "Field" and if i do a `<xsl:value of select="@type" />` i get "fld". But if i do a `<xsl:value of select="." />` i get the value inside `<td:value>` that is 25.

My concern is that i need to get the value of the 'passed' attribute inside td:value. I am able to access the attribute if i use the following template from the current place.

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="*[@passed]" />

  <xsl:template match="*[@passed]" >
       <xsl:value-of select="@passed" />
     </xsl:template>
```

But the problem is that the 'passed' attribute might not be there always, so i need to get to the `<td:value>` node with just the nodes name.

I tried

```
<xsl:apply-templates select=".//td" />
<xsl:apply-templates select=".//td:value" />
<xsl:apply-templates select=".//*" />
<xsl:apply-templates select=".*" />
<xsl:apply-templates select="td" />
```

nothing seems to work. How do i get to that td:value node from the Field node ?

Comment: Does your XSLT know the `td:` namespace?

Comment: Yes there is a xmlns:td="somewebsite" namespace declaration present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to clarify, you are currently positioned on the **field** element, and you are trying to select the child **td:value** to get its **@passed** attribute, but if this attribute is not there, you want to get the get the value of the element instead.

Well, what you could do is first do, is replace this

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="*[@passed]" />
```

With just this

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
```

Then, you need two matching templates; one for when the attribute is present, and one to capture other cases

```
<xsl:template match="Field/*[@passed]" >
   <xsl:value-of select="@passed" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Field/*" >
   <xsl:value-of select="." />
</xsl:template>
```

When you have two templates like this, XSLT will match the more specific one first. So, if a **@passed** attribute is present, the first template will always be matched (even though the second template also matches it). When there is not one present, the second one will be used.

EDIT: If you don't want to specify the element name, you could replace your templates with just this...

```
<xsl:template match="*[@passed]" >
   <xsl:value-of select="@passed" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*" >
   <xsl:value-of select="." />
</xsl:template>
```

However, these will start to match all elements which could affect other parts of your XSLT. So, you might have to make use of the **mode** parameter here

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="*" mode="Field" />

<xsl:template match="*[@passed]" mode="Field" >
   <xsl:value-of select="@passed" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*" mode="Field" >
   <xsl:value-of select="." />
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Hey Tim, thanks for the quick answer. I forgot to mention one more constrain. The tag 'Field' is not consistent, it might be different in each case. So how to reference the template now instead of "Field/*[@passed]" and "Field/*" ?

Comment: Ahh, i totally forgot about the mode parameter. It works fine now. Thanks a lot for your help man!

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare the same namespace that is assigned to the `td` prefix of `td:value` in the input XML. For instance:

```
<foo xmlns:td="urn:td">
  <Fieldid="123" type="fld" elem="3">
    <td:value passed="true"> 25 </td:value>
  </Field>
</foo>
```

The XSLT could be something like:

```
<xsl:template match="Field">
  <xsl:if test="td:value@passed" xmlns:td="urn:td">
    <xsl:value-of select="td:value"/>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

The important part is that the namespace be the same as in the input document, it doesn't matter if the prefix in the XSLT document is named differently. If possible and if all XML is under your control, it should be, for clarity.

Comment: Paulo, wont the `<xsl:value-of select="td:value"/>` work without mentioning the xmlns:td in the template? Is it mandatory ?

Comment: To match specifically on `td:value`, yes. You may declare the namespace in any containing node, like the root `xsl:stylesheet`. However, if you really want to disregard the namespace, try `<xsl:template match="local-name(.) = 'value'">`.